# Using a file PATH with a colon in Windows file system

Tags: c++, windows, file, stream, ntfs

What does the colon in the PATH (for example `"a:data.dat"`) mean in Windows file system.

In the following C++ code:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("a:data.dat");
```

I'm using Windows OS and It works fine when reading/writing but I cannot find the "data.dat" part in the name of the file stored. There is only a file named "a" with 0 bytes after writing.

Comment: *What does the colon in the PATH mean?* -- Your operating system command-shell has those details.  This doesn't look like a C++ issue.

Comment: On some systems the "a:" refers to a specific drive. On other systems "a:" is a valid  prefix on a file. It depends on your OS (or more specifically the File System being used by the OS).

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NTFS file system supports multiple [*File Streams*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams) per file, where the file name and stream name are separated by `:`. Every file has a default unnamed stream, but can also have additional named streams.

What you describe sounds like you have created a file `a` that contains a secondary stream named `data.dat`, and then you are writing your data to that stream.

When you later try to read/view the file, if the default stream is accessed instead of the `data.dat` stream, it will seem like no data had been written to the file at all.  But it really was written to, and you would need to open the `data.dat` stream in order to read its data.

FYI, most apps don't know anything about these secondary file streams, so they only read/write the default stream. Which would explain the symptom you are experiencing.